# How do I solve the uiTableview scrolling app crash which throws array index out of bound exception in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am loading data and updating the cell, when I scroll quickly the app crashes and throws array index out of bound at cellforrowat: index path. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: There is no way to tell what the problem is unless you post the relevant code.

Comment: Okay, I will share it.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableView is trying to access data from your data source which actually does not exist.

Assuming you have a data source like this.

```
let dataSource = [[String]]()
```

Then your table view delegate methods should look like this.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return dataSource[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
     
   //your code     
}
```